# SQL Server : INSERT with a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to insert into my `Files-Favorites` table only if the values I'm trying to pass isn't in there already.

I tried:

```
INSERT INTO [Files-Favorites](fileID,auditorID)  
     VALUES ('1', '34') 
      WHERE (fileID != '1' 
        AND auditorID != '34')
```

This doesn't work. I'm trying not to `INSERT` duplicate values. How do I pull this off? This is for a Microsoft SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using if not exists

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [Files-Favorites] WHERE fileID = '1' AND auditorID = '34') 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO [Files-Favorites](fileID, auditorID) 
    VALUES('1', '34') 
END
```

Comment: this is not TRANSACTION safe

Answer (score 2):

I would use a composite (multi-column) key rather than checking on each insert

```
ALTER TABLE [Files-Favorites] ADD CONSTRAINT unique_1 UNIQUE(fileID,auditorID)
```

Comment: this is way beyond me, not sure what you mean here

Comment: you can add unique constraint to prevent duplicate data. It is not good practice to check on each insert.

Answer (score 1):

We can use EXISTS with sub query to check the data existence and insert accordingly:

```
INSERT INTO [Files-Favorites](fileID,auditorID) 
SELECT fileID, auditorID FROM (
SELECT '1' fileID,'34' auditorID) t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT tm.fileID FROM [Files-Favorites] tm 
                 WHERE tm.fileID = t.fileID AND tm.auditorID = t.auditorID)
```